# Do we have any approach for model interpretation in LLAMA2 text classification?

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, llama, xai

I want to perform text classification using LLAMA2. The classification has two categories: positive and negative. However, I also want to identify the keywords based on which LLAMA2 made the classification.
Please share any approach for this problem.

Comment: Asking for recommendations on libraries and tools is explicitly off topic.  Please read the rules and guidelines before posting questions.

Comment: oh. I will edit the question. And will ask for approach instead of tool/library